# How to let the children of the row to be in other line if the children exceed the width of the device

Tags: flutter

I want to let the children that exceed the width of the device to be in the below line how to achieve this with the Row widget
[image]

code
[image]

Comment: Can you include your code snippet that will reproduce the same issue? And what will be ui when items overflow

Comment: @YeasinSheikh done, i want to let the children that exceed the width to get down to another line

Comment: Please post code as text, not as an image.  This makes it easier for others to reproduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  [`Wrap`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) in this case.

```dart
Wrap(
  spacing: 8.0, // gap between adjacent chips
  runSpacing: 4.0, // gap between lines
  children:[
    Chip(
      avatar: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: const Text('AH')),
      label: const Text('Hamilton'),
    ),
   
  ],
)
```

Ref and more about [`Wrap`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) .